# Valid output types for play twirl template

Tags: playframework-2.5, twirl

What are the valid types that can be generated by a Twirl template in play framework?  I know that I can generate HTML.  I would like to generate an svg.  Is that possible?

If I have a file named foo.scala.html, then I do get a generated class.  foo.scala.svg does not result in a class.

Are the options documented anywhere?

I am currently using PlayFramework 2.5.2, but upgrading should be possible.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomTemplateFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the valid types that can be generated by a Twirl template in play framework?

https://github.com/playframework/twirl#template-files:

> Template files must be named {name}.scala.{ext} where ext can be html, js, xml, or txt.

> I would like to generate an svg. Is that possible?

Not out of the box. You can implement a custom format yourself though. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomTemplateFormat